# HttpClientBuilder class crashing without any exception

Tags: java, exception, httpclient

I am trying to make an HTTP request with Java but the `HttpClientBuilder` crashes without any exception.

This is my code:

```
public static JSONObject makeRequest(String url) {
    JSONObject json = null;
    String strResponse = "";
    
    try {
        System.out.println("1");
        HttpClientBuilder clientBuilder = HttpClientBuilder.create();
        System.out.println("2");
        CloseableHttpClient httpClient = clientBuilder.build();
        System.out.println("3");
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    
    return null;
}
```

The code prints:

```
1
2
```

And crashes in this line:

```
CloseableHttpClient httpClient = clientBuilder.build();
```

without any exception.

How can I fix the problem?

Comment: add a try catch block to catch the exception it's throwing

Comment: @VFX you can see the print :\ and i checked with break point

Comment: @SaifAhmad i added try and catch and its the same issue

Comment: I ran the code on my Laptop and it prints 1,2,3 without any exceptions. The parameter URL is not getting used at any place.

Comment: @SaifAhmad ok salif so how can its help me that in your pc its working? how can i see the exceptions....

Comment: what does "crashing" mean exactly?

Comment: @Eugene the app finished in this line: "ttpClientBuilder clientBuilder = HttpClientBuilder.create();" without any exception.

Comment: this is going to be impossible to answer. How about you debug this and may be see how far it reaches inside `clientBuilder.build()`.